# How to fix Access Violation at address in Delphi

Tags: oop, delphi

I'm new to delphi and am trying to start OOP. However I get an access violation when using public property to set a private field.

```
type
  User = class;
  TData = class
  private
    CurrUser: User;
    Connection: TFDConnection;
    Query: TFDQuery;

  procedure SetUser(newUser: User);
  procedure SetConnection(newConn: TFDConnection);
  procedure SetQuery(newQry: TFDQuery);
public
  property CUser: User read CurrUser write SetUser;
  property Conn: TFDConnection read Connection write SetConnection;
  property Qry: TFDQuery read Query write SetQuery;

  class procedure Login(uID: integer); static;
  class procedure Logout(uID: integer); static;
  class procedure ExitApp(); static;
end;
implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TData.SetUser(newUser: User);
begin
  CurrUser := newUser;
end;

procedure TData.SetConnection(newConn: TFDConnection);
begin
  Connection := newConn;
end;

procedure TData.SetQuery(newQry: TFDQuery);
begin
  Query := newQry;
end;
```

I expect to be able to set the Connection using that property however it gives me the access violation with any code that uses the property write:
TData.Conn.LoginPrompt := False;
TData.Conn.Connected := True;

```
var
  TData: frmData.TData;
  LoginForm: TLoginForm;
  ErrorCount : integer;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TLoginForm.ExitAppButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TData.ExitApp;
end;

procedure TLoginForm.LoginButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  companyPath : string;
  nurseID : integer;
begin
  if(UsernameInput.Text = '') or (PasswordInput.Text = '') or (PincodeInput.Text = '') then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter your login details.');
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    TData.Conn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
    TData.Conn.Params.DriverID := 'MSAcc';
    TData.Conn.Params.Database := 'D:\PulseDB\AlfaPersonnel\Pulse.mdb';
    TData.Conn.LoginPrompt := False;
    TData.Conn.Connected := True;
    if(TData.Conn.Connected <> True) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Could not connect, try again');
      Exit;
    end
    else //When Connection
    begin
      TData.Qry := TFDQuery.Create(TData.Conn);
      try
        TData.Qry.Connection := TData.Conn;
        TData.Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM NurseLogin WHERE Username=:uname AND Password=:pword AND PinCode=:pin;';
        TData.Qry.Params.ParamByName('uname').AsString := UsernameInput.Text;
        TData.Qry.Params.ParamByName('pword').AsString := PasswordInput.Text;
        TData.Qry.Params.ParamByName('pin').AsString := PincodeInput.Text;
        TData.Qry.Active := True;

        if TData.Qry.RecordCount = 0 then ShowMessage('Details not recognised.')
        else if TData.Qry.RecordCount = 1 then
             begin
               if TData.Qry.FieldByName('IsActive').AsBoolean then //If the user is active
               begin
                 try
                   //Connect to the path
                   companyPath := TData.Qry.FieldByName('CompanyName').AsString;
                   TData.Conn.Params.Database := 'D\PulseDB\' + companyPath + '\Pulse.mdb';
                   TData.Conn.Connected := True;

                   ShowMessage('Connected to ' + companyPath);
                 finally

                 end;
               end;
             end;
      finally
      end;
    end;
  finally
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Has `TData.Conn` (or it's underlying TData.Connection) been assigned a value ? You can't assign to `TData.Conn.LoginPrompt` or `TData.Conn.Connected` before it has.

Comment: We need to see the code where you are using TData. At a guess I would say you are not creating the object before using it.

Comment: @KeithMiller I've just added that for you, if there's any more I need to add please let me know cheers

Comment: You have a type TData and a variable TData. That is very confusing for me, and, I am sure for you. The compiler might be a bit confused too! . I would start by changing the name of your variable.

Comment: @WiliamCardoso Thanks, where do you assign a value to the TData global variable?

Comment: @Dsm Okay, so I renamed the variable, and now theres a load of errors, i've changed the global variable to Data: TData , however if I use e.g Data.ExitApp it gives an error 'TValue does not contain a member called ExitApp', why isn't Data being recognised as TData?

Comment: I would need to see your uses clause to answer that. It is possibly being seen as a different TData. You have ExitApp as a class procedure. Normally you would call a class procedure as TData.AppExit, in your case. Maybe you did not intend it to be a class procedure. (A *class* procedure operates at class level, not instance (variable) level. Perhaps you misunderstood that). That said, you should still be to call it using a variable, I believe (although I never do...)

Comment: What address?..

Comment: There are numerous examples of this kind of login and data access on SO.  You might do better to study some of those than to try and re-invent this wheel and bring a whole new set of problems on yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever create an instance of your `TData` class. At some point you need to write:

```
TData := frmData.TData.Create;
```

Which is how you instantiate an instance. And you need to destroy it when you are finished also. Like this:

```
TData.Free;
```

That you did not instantiate an instance is the explanation for your access violation.

Some other issues:

1. Use the `T` prefix for types. Your variable should be named `Data` rather than `TData`.
2. Don't use global variables if at all possible.

Comment: I wanted to use the data variable across all my forms isnt having it as a global variable the only way or is there something else I can do for that? Also I have renamed my global variable to Data: TData however I still get error in the TLoginForm.LoginButtonClick procedure -- Data.Conn := //Anything (Error: TValue does not contain a member named conn)

Comment: Step 1 when you encounter an error message is to read it. It says "TValue does not ...". So, ask yourself why it is talking about `TValue`. It seems that `Data: TData` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: So, why does it think it's a TValue, and i have no clue how to answer that :/ Edit, forgot data is used for something else lol changed the variable to VData

Comment: But anyhow, now your comment asks about issues with code that is different from that in the question. You ask a question. We answer it. In the meantime you change your code. Now you are asking about code that is different from that you originally asked about. What now? We answer this new question. But will your code stay still? Not likely. Frustrating isn't it. I answered the question about the access violation. You need to take that on board and slow down.

Comment: What David means is: don't change the question when it is answered, otherwise the answer does not match the question anymore. If you have other, new questions when your current question is answered, post a **new** one and don't change the current one. Otherwise people see that it doesn't make sense to answer your questions and stay away from them.